# Transform data when all data is present

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, transformation

i am trying to transform some elasticsearch documents before indexing them into my index using a filter. My intention is to aggregate all couples of "started" & "completed" dates of phase2 and to calculate the duration, avoiding transformation of documents without their match, i.e: documents with "started" must have their corresponding "completed" document to be transformed "together". Here is the index definition:

```
{
    "my-index": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "_class": { //Spring-data-elastic
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": false,
                    "doc_values": false
                },
                "keyA": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "creationDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "keyB": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "keyC": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "phase1CompletionDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "phase1StartDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "phase2CompletionDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "phase2StartDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "phase3CompletionDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "phase3StartDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "phaseName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "phaseStatus": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "routing": {
                    "allocation": {
                        "include": {
                            "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "refresh_interval": "1s",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "my-index",
                "creation_date": "1647362152302",
                "store": {
                    "type": "fs"
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "AVQvC8NfTCym7dKIDRXsRA",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7160399"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a "completed" document looks like this:

```
{
    "keyA": "9",
    "keyB": "0F79",
    "keyC": "11111",
    "creationDate": "2022-03-15T16:36:33",
    "phaseName": "phase2",
    "phaseStatus": "completed",
    "phase2CompletionDate": "2022-02-17T12:27:10"
}
```

and the transform preview API call looks like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_transform/_preview' -d '{ 
   "source": {
        "index": "my-index",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "exists": { "field": "phase2StartDate" }
                    },
                    {
                        "exists": { "field": "phase2CompletionDate" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "my-aggr-index"
    },
    "pivot": {
        "group_by": {
            "keyA": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "keyA"
                }
            },
            "keyB": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "keyB"
                }
            },
            "keyC": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "keyC"
                }
            }
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "phase2Duration.startedTime": { "max": { "field": "phase2StartDate" } },
            "phase2Duration.completedTime": { "max": { "field": "phase2CompletionDate" } },
            "total_duration": {
                "bucket_script": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                        "phase2start": "phase2Duration.startedTime.value",
                        "phase2completetd": "phase2Duration.completedTime.value"
                    },
                    "script": "(params.phase2completetd - params.phase2start ) / 1000"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "dates_as_epoch_millis": "true"
    },
    "frequency": "5m"
 }'
```

want to avoid getting:

```
{
    "keyA": "9",
    "keyB": "0F79",
    "keyC": "11111",
    "phase2Duration": {
        "startedTime": null,
        "completedTime": "2022-02-17T12:27:10"        
    }
}
```

whereas given the proper "started" & "completed" pair will have the desired result that looks like:

```
{
    "total_duration": 1200,
    "keyA": "3",
    "keyB": "0F79",
    "keyC": "11111",
    "phase2Duration": {
        "startedTime": "2022-02-17T12:27:10",
        "completedTime": "2022-02-17T12:47:10"
    }
}
```

is it possible? if so, how could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

got it :)

added the following block after the "total_duration" aggregation added another block:

```
"my_bucket_filter": {
    "bucket_selector": {
       "buckets_path": {
         "totally": "total_duration.value"
       },
       "script": "params.totally !=null"
    }
}
```